# Copy EAP to EABase.eap through c#

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I have a custom EAP file which I want to use for the creation of further EAP.
I want to copy this custom EAP Template to any other new EAP, before proceeding further.
I am using createModel: which copies the BaseEap to the destination EAP.

```
repository.CreateModel(CreateModelType.cmEAPFromBase, "path EAP currently opened",-1);
```

How can I can copy my custom Template EAP to Base EAP??
Is there a direct way to copy EAP To EAP using c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by using **Project Transfer**  using the below code

```
Repository.GetProjectInterface().ProjectTransfer(EAPFilesourcepath,EAPFiletargetpath,EAPFilelogpath);
```

Using  this you can transfer your template EAP to your new EAP and the work further

> Data Transfer may Fail due to one of the following reasons
>
> 1. the Source File does not exist
> 2. the Target File already exists
> 3. the Target File is not an EAP File, only EAP files are supported in Automation Interface

Comment: The posted image contains copyrighted material. It's from Sparx Systems' help file for Enterprise Architect.

Comment: @Uffe Yep Removed, Thanks for info

Comment: @dahsra thanks for the info. I tried as suggested by you . I am getting following exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception.

Comment: thanks , I am able to copy . but I have one problem , my Target EAP already exists and is opened in EA. how can I copy to already existing EAP??

Comment: @Akanksha you need to transfer your template EAP to an old existing EAp file ?  why should you do that

Comment: @Akanksha you can see it in log , Data Transfer may Fail due to one of the following reasons 
1. the Source File does not exist 
2. the Target File already exists 
3. the Target File is not an EAP File, only EAP files are supported in Automation Interface

Comment: thanks @dahsra my target EAP was existing that's why exception came.

Comment: @dahsra my requirement was to copy the template EAP file while creation of new EAP. so once new EAP was created, I was trying to copy my template. But now I am just passing the new EAP name to the ProjectTransfer and it is creating EAP with copied template for me.